# Using javascript for form validation in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have been looking at some examples of form validation, where an invalid input will stop the user before proceeding to the next page. The way I have seen this done many times is using the event.preventDefault() function, but it just doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm not sure if the javascript function is wrong, or maybe it is just not being read at all. When I send in an invalid input it goes through to the next page anyway.

Here is my HTML code:

Header:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="3.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="3.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>
```

Body:

```
<section>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div id="loginInfo">

    <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="nextpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table id="loginTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="loginInput" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="emailError" class="errorMsg"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" class="loginInput" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="passError" class="errorMsg"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></br><input type="submit" name="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

and here is the referenced 3.js code:

```
document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", loginFunction, false);

function loginFunction(event)
{
    var valid= true;

    var elements= event.currentTarget;
    var email= elements[0].value;
    var pass= elements[1].value;

    var regexEmail= /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/; 
    var regexPass= /^(\S*)?\d+(\S*)?\W+$/;

    var emailError= document.getElementById(emailError);
    var passError= document.getElementById(passError);

    if (email == null || email == ""){
        emailError.innerHTML= "Email is empty";
        valid= false;
    }
    else if (regexEmail.test(email) == false){
        emailError.innerHTML= "Incorrect Email format";
        valid= false;
    }

    if (pass == null || pass == ""){
        passError.innerHTML= "Password is empty.";
        valid = false;
    }
    else if (regexPass.test(pass) == false) {
        passError.innerHTML= "Incorrect password format";
        valid = false;
    }
    else if (pass.length < 8){
        passError.innerHTML= "Password is too short, must be 8+ characters";
        valid= false;
    }

    if (valid == false){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain where i've made my error?

Comment: Guessing because you're including the script in `<head>` the form isn't available yet. Check your console for errors.

Comment: it's really hard to answer your question as the whole picture is not there in your snippets. Such as `emailError` and `passError` elements are not listed. But I suggest to start debugging from adding `defer` attribite to your script tag if its in the `head` block.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what error you are encountering? Is it partially functional, or is absolutely no change occurring when you hit the button no matter what your inputs are?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<section>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div id="loginInfo">    
    <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="nextpage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table id="loginTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="loginInput" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="emailError" class="errorMsg"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" class="loginInput" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="passError" class="errorMsg"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></br><input type="button" name="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

And this:

```
document.getElementById('loginSubmit').addEventListener('click',loginFunction,false);
function loginFunction()
{
    var valid=true;
    var elements=event.currentTarget;
    var email=elements[0].value;
    var pass=elements[1].value;
    var regexEmail=/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/; 
    var regexPass=/^(\S*)?\d+(\S*)?\W+$/;
    var emailError=document.getElementById(emailError);
    var passError=document.getElementById(passError);
    if(email==null||email=='')
    {
        emailError.innerHTML='Email is empty';
        valid=false;
    }
    else if(regexEmail.test(email)==false)
    {
        emailError.innerHTML='Incorrect Email format';
        valid=false;
    }
    if(pass==null||pass=='')
    {
        passError.innerHTML='Password is empty.';
        valid=false;
    }
    else if(regexPass.test(pass)==false) 
    {
        passError.innerHTML='Incorrect password format';
        valid=false;
    }
    else if(pass.length<8)
    {
        passError.innerHTML='Password is too short, must be 8+ characters';
        valid=false;
    }
    if(!valid)
    {
        return
    }
    document.getElementById('LoginForm').submit();  
}
```